# How to test a callback function using jest?

Tags: node.js, express, unit-testing, jestjs

I am making an express js api, I wanted to test verifyToken middleware which uses jwt.verify method to verify the given token. The following is the middleware code

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const {StatusCodes} = require('http-status-codes');
const express = require('express');

function verifyToken(jwt) {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    const header = req.headers['authorization'];
    if (!header) {
      console.log(res.status().send());
      res.status(StatusCodes.UNAUTHORIZED)
          .send({message: 'No token provided.'});
      return;
    }

    const token = header.split(' ')[1];
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(StatusCodes.UNAUTHORIZED)
            .send({message: 'Unauthorized.'});
        return;
      }
      req.userId = decoded.id;
      next();
    });
  };
}

module.exports = {main: verifyToken(jwt), test: verifyToken};
```

I want to mock test the jwt module using jest. the jwt.verify method returns a callback after verification. How can I test that callback using unit testing?

The callback

```js
(err, decoded) => {
  if (err) {
    res.status(StatusCodes.UNAUTHORIZED)
       .send({message: 'Unauthorized.'});
    return;
  }

  req.userId = decoded.id;
  next();
}
```

How can I test this middleware?

I have checked Jest documentation for [testing callbacks](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#callbacks). But the example code provided gives the callback function directly as a function parameter, while my code takes jwt object as a parameter and not the callback.